# How to POST to a model using django restframework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and trying to play with restframework. I have created a simple model and I'd like to POST to this model via REST and sending JSON data.

This is what I've done so far:

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'phone', 'city', 'comment', 'timestamp')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/contact/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ContactDetail.as_view()),
```

views.py

```
class ContactDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    format = None
```

but when I try to post to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/contact` I get this error

```
13. ^index.html#/verifyEmail/(?P<key>\w+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
14. ^api/contact/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$
The current URL, api/contact, didn't match any of these.
```

**Question**

How can I POST data to my model and save it?

Answer (score 0):

You got a couple of problems here:

1. You are using `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` which will provide the PUT, GET and DELETE methods. If you want to be able to POST (this means create) to that endpoint, you should be using another one. Replace it for `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, it will provide all CRUD methods. Don't forget to import the module ([+more info](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)).
2. You are trying to build the urls yourself which is not correct, drf provides [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) to build them automatically. Just follow the docs, they are really well explained.

Once you fix those issues, you will be able to POST to /api/contact/ to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that the regular expression here:

```
url(r'^api/contact/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ContactDetail.as_view())
```

does not match the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/contact
```

A match should look more like the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/contact/123412213/
```

Including the trailing slash `/`